# Sql gerado pelo Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para ver o código sql que uma expressão linq gera para ser executado pelo ADO.Net.

Estou utilizando o NHibernate como framework ORM.

Comment: Observe como opção também [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120317/2998)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça uma função como esta

```
public string GetGeneratedSql(System.Linq.IQueryable queryable, ISession session)
{
    var sessionImp = (ISessionImplementor) session;
    var nhLinqExpression = new NhLinqExpression(queryable.Expression, sessionImp.Factory);
    var translatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
    var translators = translatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(nhLinqExpression, null, false, sessionImp.EnabledFilters, sessionImp.Factory);

    return translators[0].SQLString;
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10710451/4190610)