# Visualizar SQL em tempo de Execução

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

Existe algum monitor que me exiba o script sql em tempo de execução?

Por exemplo, durante o debug, gostaria de ver como ficou o script montado pelo seguinte código:

```
var q = (from proc in
                 Sessao.Query<Processo>()
                 Sessao.Query<MovimentoEsparta>() where mov.DtHrMov >=
                   dtInicial && mov.DtHrMov < dtFinal && e.CodDoc == 
                     mov.CodDoc select mov.CodDoc).Any())
                 from psa in Sessao.Query<ProcessoSituacaoAtual>()
                 from mpf in Sessao.Query<EspartaMpf>()
                 where proc.CodDoc == psa.CodDoc
                 && proc.CodDoc == mpf.CodDoc
                 && proc.CodTipProc != 388
                 && proc.CodTipProc != 399
                 && proc.DtAutua >= dtInicial
                 && proc.DtAutua < dtFinal
                 select new
                 {
                     proc.NumAno,
                     proc.CodDoc,
                     DtHrAutuacao = proc.DtAutua,
                     ClasseCnj = proc.CodTipProc
                 });
```

Isto é possível?
Detalhe: Utilizando NHibernate com banco Oracle com IDE VS2013 Professional (C#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível, porém ao contrário do Java e a implementação do `Hibernate`, não tem nenhuma propriedade que você simplesmente "seta" e o SQL é mostrado no LOG....

Por c#, você pode escrever/implementar um interceptador e fazer o que quiser com a query - até modificá-la em tempo real.

```
using NHibernate;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class SqlInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString OnPrepareStatement(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(sql.ToString()); //opcional, aqui você pode modificar para escrever em log, por exemplo.
        return sql;
    }
}
```

E na configuração do `NHibernate` você "grampeia" o interceptador:

```
protected virtual void Configurar(FluentConfiguration config)
{
    config.ExposeConfiguration(x =>
                                   {
                                       x.SetInterceptor(new SqlInterceptor());
                                   });
}
```

Outra solução é implementar via `Log4j`:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
     type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net debug="false">
    <appender name="WindowsDebugOutput" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender,
         log4net">
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
              value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
      </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="WindowsDebugOutput" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

E quando for abrir a `session` do `NHibernate`, você "chama" o `Log4j`:

`log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`